# Why is c + 10w in the span of u and v? Why is u, v, and w, linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let **u** and **v** be linearly independent vectors in R3 that lie on the x1-x2 plane where x3=0, and **w** = $$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
  x\\
  y\\
1
\end{array}
\right] $$ and show **u**, **v**, and **w** are linearly independent.

We are also to show that if **c** = $$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
  a\\
  b\\
-10
\end{array}
\right] $$
Then **c** + 10**w** is in the span of **u** and **v**.

Can someone explain the answer to these two questions intuitively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively, since $u$ and $v$ lies in the plane given by $x_3=0$ and are linearly independent, any vector outside this plane will be a linearly independent vector to $u$ and $v$, since it is not in the span of $u$ and $v$ (their span is necessarily the plane given by $x_3=0$, by considering dimensions). We clearly see that $w$ does not lie in that plane, so the first result follows.

The second result is just a computation. $c+10w$ clearly has third coordinate $0$, thus is contained in the plane given by $x_3=0$, which is the span of $u$ and $v$.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I assumed as well, just needed confirmation.